# An unknown item is declared as the root of your MXML document. Then all new projects create components namespace

Tags: adobe, flash-builder, mxml

I am using Flash Builder 4.6

Yesterday the project is working fine. Now it does not. It has this error.

```
An unknown item is declared as the root of your MXML document. Switch to source mode to correct it.
```

The code is fine because i exported the project to another computer also running flash builder and the project works fine.

And now whenever I create a new Project in my original laptop, i noticed that it adds an extra "components" namespace and points to spark.components.

And in design mode, whenever i drag and drop any labels, it is not showing up on the design mode.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to reinstall Flex4 or reinstall the Adobe Flash builder 4.6